# Fibonacci series using only main method recursively

Tags: c, fibonacci

I got this question from my friend who underwent an interview. The interviewer asked him to **Generate the Fibonacci series without using any function  except main**.
Means he was supposed to generate a Fibonacci series by calling the `main()` function recursively, but he wasn't able to do that. I also tried after his interview but all in vain.

Could anyone please tell their ideas in this regard?

Comment: Did they specify recursion, or was it only implied? Because you can do it in a `for` loop.

Comment: when you say not call a function do you mean not calling a library that will do it for you? Calling main sounds like a bad idea

Comment: @OrinMacGregor : no for loop ....

Comment: @ruakh No for loop only recursion of main method

Comment: My idea: don't go work for this company.

Comment: Well, it IS possible to call recursively the main method in java but it is kinda weird, since the args array is a String array which means that you should add parsing logic before making any calculations... And you should also control that recursion...

Comment: @Gamb in C calling main (recursively or not) is undefined but you can avoid using argc/argv and just print the serie stopping when it reaches an arithmetic  overflows (it will certainly occur before stack overflow)

Comment: @Kwartz: unless you can point to the appropriate section of the language standard, recursing on `main` is *not* undefined in C.

Comment: @Just noticed the Java tag is off, nevermind my comment :)

Answer (score 2):

Simple. In C:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main(b,a){a>b?main(1,0):printf("%d\n",a),main(a+b,b);}
```

In Java you need more code and a *lot* more memory and it only goes up to 65535:

```
class F{public static void main(String[]v){int x=v.length,a,b;System
.out.println(a=x>>16);main(new String[(b=x&0xFFFF)+1<<16|a+b]);}}
```

Would I get hired?

Comment: No. Undefined behavior because %u must receive an unsigned int but gets an int :-)

Comment: Well spotted! My prototype worked with unsigned ints. Corrected. I bet it totally has defined behaviour now :P

Comment: Not standard (`main` declaration is not in an acceptable C standard form), but good solution.

Comment: @ouah: Oh, I thought it started with 1 1. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fib1=0;
int fib2=1;
int fib_tmp;

int main()
{
  printf("%d ",fib1);
  fib_tmp=fib1+fib2;
  fib1=fib2;
  fib2=fib_tmp;
  if (fib1>0)
    main(); 
}
```

Silly interview questions ...
Well at least it compiles and gives accurate result for ints.

It generates the sequence "recursively" for all int representable fibonacci number :)

Comment: not this way ,it got printed but as we know that we have used fabonacci function as fob(n-2)+fob(n-1).... this way I am thinking

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static int i = 0, j= 1;
    int res, max;
    /*
     * You could add some check for argc and argv
     */
    max = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("%d ", i);
    res = i + j;
    i = j;
    j = res;

    if (j > max)
    {
        printf("\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    main(argc, argv);
}
```

Example:

```
$  gcc -std=c99 -Wall tst.c -o tst
$ ./tst 1000
0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610
$
```